# Never repeat some name

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using c# winforms.  When I click a button the program shows 2 words from the list, but sometimes the words repeat.  How I do to don't let the words repeat

This is the code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var words = new[] { "Worm", "Fast", "Death", "boat", "Sneak", "Destroction" };
    var wordsInRandomOrder = words.OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid());

    foreach (var word in wordsInRandomOrder)
    {
        textBox1.Text = word;
        break;
    }

    foreach (var word in wordsInRandomOrder)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + word;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `textBox1.Text = string.Join(" ", wordsInRandomOrder.Take(2));`?

Comment: @juharr i am new on c#

Comment: Any time you have a loop where you *always* break after the *first* iteration, chances are you don't need a loop.

Comment: Basically you don't want to iterate that sequence twice because each time the order will change and sometimes the first item will be the same.  Instead you want to just use one iteration and take 2 items from it and in this case the first 2 should be fine.

Comment: @juharr amazingly elegant solution!

Comment: @juharr put your comment as a answer

Comment: @juharr please do that, you cannot deprive the world of this elegance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var words = new[] { "Worm", "Fast", "Death", "boat", "Sneak", "Destroction" };
    var wordsInRandomOrder = words.OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
    textBox1.Text = wordsInRandomOrder[0] + " " + wordsInRandomOrder[1];
}
```

Option 2:

```
var words = new[] { "Worm", "Fast", "Death", "boat", "Sneak", "Destroction" };
Random rd = new Random();

int firstIndex = rd.Next(0, words.Length);
int secondIndex = rd.Next(0, words.Length);

while (secondIndex == firstIndex)
{
    secondIndex = rd.Next(0, words.Length);
}

textBox1.Text = words[firstIndex] + " " + words[secondIndex];
```

Comment: This creates a copy of original list, does sorting and only uses 2 items as result. Pretty inefficient if you ask me. What you basically need is 2 unique indexes.

Comment: @Sinatr Ok, I have added the second approach. Is that better?

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rd = new Random();

int firstIndex = rd.Next(0, words.Length);
int secondIndex = rd.Next(0, words.Length);

while (secondIndex == firstIndex)
{
    secondIndex = rd.Next(0, words.Length);
}

textBox1.Text = words[firstIndex] + " " + words[secondIndex];
```

Comment: where i put the name list? "Worm", "Fast", "Death", "boat", "Sneak", "Destroction"

Comment: Declare it before this line "Random rd = new Random()" as a string array, just as what u have done in your code: var words = new[] { "Worm", "Fast", "Death", "boat", "Sneak", "Destroction" };

Comment: Two answers? Can´t you decide for which one is better?

Comment: @HimBromBeere It's ok to have 2 answers. 2 presents different logic. Or maybe I should combine 2 answers into 1. Okay, lets combine.

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach that won´t use a `Guid`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    var words = new[] { "Worm", "Fast", "Death", "boat", "Sneak", "Destroction" };
    var wordsInRandomOrder = words.OrderBy(i => r.Next()).ToList();

    textBox1.Text = String.Join(" ", wordsInRandomOrder.Take(2));
}
```

With this appraoch even *if* the randomizer generates the same number twice (which is fairly unlikely) you take another word from your list as they are simply ordered. If two items have the same order-value they are ordered arbitrarily, however the same item won´t be used twice.

Comment: Could just use `r.Next()` since the value is only used for ordering and not as an index.

Answer (score 0):

If you *realllllly* want to keep the code you're using, in the second `foreach`, you can do:

```
foreach (var word in wordsInRandomOrder)
{
    if(word != textBox1.Text)
    {
       textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + word;
       break;
    }
}
```

but a much better option would be as juharr wrote:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join(" ", wordsInRandomOrder.Take(2));
```

if you want to go the route of a loop, it would probably be better to join
the two "`foreach`es" you have like so:

```
foreach (string word in wordsInRandomOrder)
{
    if(textBox1.Text = "")
    {
        textBox1.Text = word;
    }
    else
    {
        if(textBox1.Text != word)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + word;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```